# If and definedness of ENV variables

Tags: cmake

I'm a little perplexed (note this is not about the use of `$` with `ENV` and `if`).

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)
set(CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES Debug)

message("-->$ENV{foobar}<--")

if (DEFINED ENV{foobar})
    message("$foobar is defined")
else()
    message("$foobar is not defined")
endif()
```

Run via `bash` and `cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug` with no `$foobar` set, predictably the relevant output is:

```
--><--
$foobar is not defined
```

And subsequent to `export foobar=1`:

```
-->1<--
$foobar is defined
```

But now:

```
> export foobar=
```

I realize this does leave the variable in the environment (vs. totally removing it with, eg., the bash built-in `unset`), but it is with a value that would be conventionally considered by many or most users as "undefined".  Unfortunately, `cmake` doesn't see it that way, however:

```
> export foobar=
> cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug
--><--
$foobar is defined
```

While I can remember this, there is no way I am going to presume normal users building my project are.  So that means no more `if (DEFINED ENV{foobar})`.

Fortunately there are simple work-arounds to this, such as testing via a proxy variable:

```
set(Foobar $ENV{foobar})
message("==>${Foobar}<==")
if (DEFINED Foobar)
    message("Internal Foobar defined")
else()
    message("Internal foobar is not defined")
endif()
```

The output is now

```
--><--
$foobar is defined
==><==
Internal foobar is not defined
```

To be fair to cmake, this is not inconsistent -- the internal foobar would be defined as an empty string too if `$ENV{foobar}` were quoted in the assignment.

My question is just to verify that I have not missed something.

Comment: Did you try `if (DEFINED ENV{foobar} AND NOT ENV{foobar} STREQUAL "")` to also check for an empty string?

Comment: Actually you have to use `AND NOT "$ENV{foobar}"`, which is a confusing exception to not using `$` in `if`; otherwise `STREQUAL` will always fail.  So really the test should just be `if (NOT "$ENV{foobar" STREQUAL "")`, which works.  If you want to put that as an answer, please do!

Comment: Ah yes, sorry I forgot to add that in the syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do the following:

`> export foobar=`

CMake's `ENV` recognizes `foobar` as defined, but it is simply defined as an empty string. Thus, you can expand your if-statement to include an empty string check using [`STREQUAL`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/if.html#condition-syntax):

```
if (DEFINED ENV{foobar} AND NOT "$ENV{foobar}" STREQUAL "")
    message("$foobar is set")
else()
    message("$foobar is not set")
endif()
```

Comment: You don't need the DEFINED bit at all, since `"$ENV{foobar}"` would be the same as `""`.